# Loop give me only the first row (puppeteer js)

Tags: javascript, node.js, puppeteer

i am trying to get price and seller data, but i only get the first row, why?
I am trying to learn js, but here i spend lot of time, please help.

i get the code from different sites and modify it for my requirements, but still not working

Puppeteer js, nodejs

```
var url = 'https://www.amazon.co.uk/gp/offer-listing/3770436385/ref=olp_f_used?ie=UTF8&f_new=true&f_usedAcceptable=true&f_usedGood=true&f_used=true&f_usedLikeNew=true&f_usedVeryGood=true';

const puppeteer = require('puppeteer');

(async function main(){
    try{

        const browser = await puppeteer.launch({headless: false });
        const page = await browser.newPage();
        page.setUserAgent('Mozilla/5.0 (X11; Linux x86_64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) HeadlessChrome/67.0.3372.0 Safari/537.36');

        await page.goto(url);
        await page.waitForSelector('div.navFooterLine:nth-child(6)');

        const sections = await page.$$('.olpOffer');

        console.log(sections.length);

        for (const section of sections){

            const result = await page.evaluate(() => {
                //  let amaOffer = document.querySelector('#olpOfferList img').innerText;
                //  let amaPrice = document.querySelector('#olpOfferList img').innerText;
                let seller = document.querySelector('.a-text-bold a').innerText;
                let price = document.querySelector('.olpOfferPrice').innerText;

                return {
                //  amaOffer,
                    seller,
                    price

            }

        } )
        console.log(result);
    }

    } catch (e) {
        console.log('Our  error', e);
    }


})();
```

Comment: Note: The indentation of your code here makes the `for` loop boundaries very, very, very misleading.  Please use consistent and accurate indentation when writing code in any language.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I know where the problems are.

1. The Puppeteer JS run javascript in two engine, both are different scopes, so we need to pass the `section` number to `page.evaluate`
2. The Amazon site display results with products from Amazon itself, and the selector doesn't select the right one, so i've changed it to `.olpSellerName`
3. I've add some improvements to make the script run fast.

Hope this can help.

```
let url = 'https://www.amazon.co.uk/gp/offer-listing/3770436385/ref=olp_f_used?ie=UTF8&f_new=true&f_usedAcceptable=true&f_usedGood=true&f_used=true&f_usedLikeNew=true&f_usedVeryGood=true'
let chromeUA = 'Mozilla/5.0 (X11; Linux x86_64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/67.0.3372.0 Safari/537.36'

const puppeteer = require('puppeteer')

;(async function main() {
    try {

        const browser = await puppeteer.launch({headless: false})
        const page = (await browser.pages())[0]
        page.setUserAgent(chromeUA)
        page.setDefaultNavigationTimeout(0)
        page.setRequestInterception(true)

        page.on('request', async request => {
            if  (
                    request.resourceType() === 'image' ||
                    request.resourceType() === 'media' ||
                    request.resourceType() === 'script' ||
                    request.resourceType() === 'stylesheet' ||
                    request.resourceType() === 'font' ||
                    request.resourceType() === 'other'
                ) {
                request.abort()
            } else {
                request.continue()
            }
        })

        await page.goto(url)
        await page.waitForSelector('div.navFooterLine:nth-child(6)')
        const sections = await page.$$('.olpOffer')

        let results = []

        for (let num = 0; num < sections.length; num++) {
            let result = await page.evaluate( (num) => {
                let seller = document.querySelectorAll('.olpSellerName')[num].innerText
                let price = document.querySelectorAll('.olpOfferPrice')[num].innerText

                return {
                    //  amaOffer,
                    seller,
                    price
                }

            }, num)
            results.push(result)
        }
        // see all results here
        console.log(results)
        return results

    } catch (e) {
        console.log('Our  error', e);
    }
})()
```

---

I have an additional question:

i want to loop for different amazonsites

```
let AmazonSites = ['de','co.uk','ca'];
for(AmazonSite of AmazonSites){

let url = 'https://www.amazon.'+ AmazonSite +'/gp/offer-listing/'+ Asin +'/ref=olp_f_used?ie=UTF8&f_new=true&f_usedAcceptable=true&f_usedGood=true&f_used=true&f_usedLikeNew=true&f_usedVeryGood=true';


await page.goto(url)
```

So you can make multiple requests by repeating the script via for loop

```
let domains = ['co.uk', 'de', 'ca']
let url = 'https://www.amazon.tld/gp/offer-listing/3770436385/ref=olp_f_used?ie=UTF8&f_new=true&f_usedAcceptable=true&f_usedGood=true&f_used=true&f_usedLikeNew=true&f_usedVeryGood=true'
let chromeUA = 'Mozilla/5.0 (X11; Linux x86_64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/67.0.3372.0 Safari/537.36'

const puppeteer = require('puppeteer')

;(async function main() {
    try {

        const browser = await puppeteer.launch({headless: false})
        const page = (await browser.pages())[0]
        page.setUserAgent(chromeUA)
        page.setDefaultNavigationTimeout(0)
        page.setRequestInterception(true)

        page.on('request', async request => {
            if  ( request.resourceType() === 'document' ) {
                request.continue()
            } else {
                request.abort()
            }
        })

        for (let tld in domains) {
            await page.goto(url.replace('tld', domains[tld]))
            await page.waitForSelector('div.navFooterLine:nth-child(6)')
            const sections = await page.$$('.olpOffer')

            let results = []

            for (let num = 0; num < sections.length; num++) {
                let result = await page.evaluate( (num) => {
                    let seller = document.querySelectorAll('.olpSellerName')[num].innerText
                    let price = document.querySelectorAll('.olpOfferPrice')[num].innerText

                    return {
                        //  amaOffer,
                        seller,
                        price
                    }

                }, num)
                results.push(result)
            }
            // see all results here
            console.log (`\n\nRESULT FOR DOMAIN TLD : www.amazon.${domains[tld]}`)
            console.log(results)
        }

        await browser.close()

    } catch (e) {
        console.log('Our  error', e);
    }
})()
```

Answer (score 1):

You're essentially doing this:

```
for (const section of sections) {
   const result = someValue;
   console.log(result);
}
```

So, you're just declaring a new `result` variable over an over in the loop, not accumulating each of the separate results into an array so you can have all the results.

It's not 100% clear where you want the results, but you can at least accumulate them into an array like this:

```
(async function main() {
    try {

        const browser = await puppeteer.launch({headless: false});
        const page = await browser.newPage();
        page.setUserAgent('Mozilla/5.0 (X11; Linux x86_64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/67.0.3372.0 Safari/537.36');
        await page.goto(url);
        await page.waitForSelector('div.navFooterLine:nth-child(6)');
        const sections = await page.$$('.olpOffer');

        console.log(sections.length);

        let results = [];

        for (const section of sections) {

            const result = await page.evaluate(() => {
                //  let amaOffer = document.querySelector('#olpOfferList img').innerText;
                //  let amaPrice = document.querySelector('#olpOfferList img').innerText;
                let seller = document.querySelector('.a-text-bold a').innerText;
                let price = document.querySelector('.olpOfferPrice').innerText;

                return {
                    //  amaOffer,
                    seller,
                    price

                }

            });
            console.log(result);
            results.push(result);
        }
        // see all results here
        console.log(results);
        return results;

    } catch (e) {
        console.log('Our  error', e);
    }
})();
```

Comment: Thank you for it, but still i get only one row.

Comment: First, what is the value of `sections.length`?  Second, when you say you still only  get one row, what exactly do you mean?  What EXACT debug output do you see that indicates that?